# Compton scattering: What is the probability distribution of different scattering angles depending on applied wavelength?

Tags: photons, electrons, scattering

Compton scattering: What is the probability distribution of different scattering angles depending on applied wavelength? As I understand the physics of waves shorter wavelengths are like tiny bullets that should scatter the electron equaly at any angle but should do the same a longer wavelength as it should be less confined to a tiny volume so acting like a 'tennis racket'.. so should the larger scattering angles for longer wavelengths be less probable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's interesting (+1). I think (not sure) a wave interpretation of Compton effect is also needed to answer this question. For example see this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0506211